# Realistic bullet material

Tags: materials

So I've been trying to model a reallistic .338 Lapua Magnum bullet.

I managed to model the base mesh, but whenever I try and add a copper material it just doesnt look right.

Here's what I got so far.

[image]

And I would like it to look like this, with some more wear and scratches from exiting the rifle.

[image]

Any tips on how to achieve this?

EDIT:
Thank you all for your help.

I added a subdivision surface, a bevel and some surface imperfections, the bullet looks great now.

I tried to add in some rifle marks by using a radial array and then inset the markings into the bullet. I'm getting these jagged artifacts. I tried added a subdivion surface to the cutter but that doesnt work.

[image]
[image]

Any idea how I could smoothen that out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this material setup, give your *Principled BSDF* a copper color, put the *Metallic* value up to 1, plug a *Noise Texture* into the *Roughness* input in order to have some dirt on the reflection, maybe add a bit of bump:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a go tommorow!

Answer (score 2):

Principled BSDF shader, orange color, little to no roughness, high metallic amount, and add scratches and imperfections. (Free online in places, [here](https://www.artstation.com/marketplace/p/3yAy/free-surface-imperfections-pack) for example, added to the principled with methods like [this.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0pYgvFdz4Y))

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also add a subdivision surface modifier to your mesh; your bullet looks a little low-poly.

Comment: Thank you both, I'll give this a go tommorow! I also added a subdivision surface and it already looks a lot better. :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all, I added the subdivision surface and followed moonboots texture settings and it looks a LOT better. I will try and add some scratches tomorrow!

[Test Render](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e8JCLcLo65wTGYTdYeSow_h2IYrsae3S/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Also add a slight bevel on the tips!

Comment: Hello, please don't use the Your Answer field for comments, instead use Add a comment, or edit your initial question  ;)

Comment: And clicking the "Accept" checkbox next to your favorite answer rewards the person who answered extra Internet points. :)

Comment: @RonJensen Thank you for the tip!